# spacing in math equation latex+tikz

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I am trying to control the size of math operators and at the same time the spacing between operators and operands using the following code.

```
\setlength{\thinmuskip}{10mu}
\setlength{\medmuskip}{2mu}
\setlength{\thickmuskip}{10mu}

\node[font=\sffamily\fontsize{11}{10},below=-0.5mm,pos=0.85,sloped]   {$\mathbf{p} \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{\(-\)} o \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{=} \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{\(-\)}2$};
```

Space skipping is working fine if there is no scalebox in the equation. But the skippers doesn't work in presence of scalebox.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit what you are trying to do here? Please make your code compilable and show one working and one not-working (the one above) node. Right now, I have difficulty to see the issue here as you are tweaking around a lot with the standard math.

Comment: `\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{${}-{}$}` will give you back your spacing. Or `\mathbin{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{$-$}}`.

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:latex3]? Are you into expl3 development?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi That tag is often wrongly applied I think, there is nothing related  to [tag:latex3] that I can see here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a look on the different versions below. You will have to choose. In my eyes, the last version should be what you are trying to do.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\newcommand{\spaceskipping}[1]{\newline{\setlength{\thinmuskip}{10mu}
    \setlength{\medmuskip}{2mu}
    \setlength{\thickmuskip}{10mu} #1}}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
% original version
$\mathbf{p} - o = -2$
\spaceskipping{$\mathbf{p} - o = -2$}

% your version
$\mathbf{p} \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{\(-\)} o \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{=} \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{\(-\)}2$
\spaceskipping{$\mathbf{p} \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{\(-\)} o \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{=} \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{\(-\)}2$}

% version by resetting the spacing of operators with surrounding {}
$\mathbf{p} \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{${}-{}$} o \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{${}={}$} \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{${}-{}$}2$
\spaceskipping{$\mathbf{p} \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{${}-{}$} o \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{${}={}$} \scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{${}-{}$}2$}

% version by resetting the spacing of operators by \mathrel resp. \mathbin
$\mathbf{p} \mathbin{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{$-$}} o \mathrel{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{$=$}} \mathbin{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{$-$}}2$
\spaceskipping{$\mathbf{p} \mathbin{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{$-$}} o \mathrel{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{$=$}} \mathbin{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{$-$}}2$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem you were seeing is that you surrounded the binary or relational operators by some group/command/environment. Therefore, the equation does not know any more, what type of symbol it has to handle here and therefore sets it as ordinary symbol `\mathord` without any spacing.

The third version resets the spacing for the operators, but scales them together with the rest. I guess, that's not what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation. Although, your comment was more than sufficient. Thanks again.

Comment: @Shahzad You are very welcome.