# How to insert a triangle/rectangle with plus sign in it (abstract algebra operators)?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

To insert the abstract algebra operators, I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newlength\triwidth
\newcommand\tridelt[1]{%
  \setlength\triwidth{\widthof{#1\ }}%
  \stackengine{-.1\triwidth}{#1\ }%
    {\scaleto{\Delta}{1\triwidth}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   C = A \tridelt{+} B, C = A \tridelt{x} B
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

as in

> [Triangle with text in it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123147/triangle-with-text-in-it)

but the result looks ugly, how to fix it?

[image: example]

Comment: Is there some reason for not using the TikZ solutions from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123147/triangle-with-text-in-it?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254509/spacing-in-math-equation-latextikz

Answer (score 7):

The symbols can be found in the in the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

[image]

```
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{equation}
  \triangleplus \triangleminus \triangletimes 
\end{equation}
```

As shown above, this package provides lots of symbols that can be used in abstract algebra (`\boxplus \boxminus \boxtimes`).

Answer (score 3):

Into the triangle you can put any symbols.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\trianglesignx[1][2.3ex]{%
  \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
  \scaleto{\stackon[0.7pt]{\color{black}$\triangle$}{\tiny $\times$}}{#1}%
}
\newcommand\trianglesignplus[1][2.3ex]{%
  \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
  \scaleto{\stackon[0.7pt]{\color{black}$\triangle$}{\tiny $\times$}}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\[\alpha \trianglesignx f(x,y)=M-M_{\alpha} \trianglesignplus\]
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT (as requested in comments):**

I made the following changes in the code:

1. Added `\mathbin` for proper spacing around the binary operators. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38984/117534) for more details.
2. Removed `\color{black}` -- not sure what that is for.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stix}
\newcommand\trianglesignx[1][2.3ex]{%
    \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
    \mathbin{%
    \scaleto{\stackon[0.7pt]{$\triangle$}{\tiny $\times$}}{#1}%
}}
\newcommand\trianglesignplus[1][2.3ex]{%
    \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
    \mathbin{%
    \scaleto{\stackon[0.7pt]{$\triangle$}{\tiny $+$}}{#1}%
}}
\begin{document}
    Custom symbols:
    \[\alpha \trianglesignx f(x,y)=M-M_{\alpha} \trianglesignplus M_{\alpha}\]

    Symbols from \verb!stix! package: 
    \[\alpha \triangletimes f(x,y)=M-M_{\alpha} \triangleplus M_{\alpha}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Hi, what's the use of `\color{black}`, and is the second one supposed to be `+` instead of `\times`? Cause I'm not getting the output you're showing with the above code

Comment: I think you should also include `\mathbin` to get proper spacing around the triangle operators. :)

Comment: I did not put the times and the symbol `+` why did I want to make it clear that within the triangle can put anything? I was hoping you would have appreciated my work. Could you edit my answer including the command `\mathbin`. For six months I'm signed up on TeX.SE and I only put two negative votes.

Comment: For the record, I'm *not* the one who downvoted your answer..

Comment: @Troy Please can you modificate my code?